# Image not saved in sd card in Canvas

Tags: android

I am using canvas drawing, it is working well but image is now saved in sd card , my code to save is

```
     mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        try {
            FileCache fileCache = new FileCache(SignatureActivity.this);
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(fileCache.getFile(imageURL));

            v.draw(canvas);
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
            mFileOutStream.flush();
            mFileOutStream.close();
            String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
            signimage.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            System.err.println("" + url);
            return url;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: you want to save image in SD card. ?? CANVAS is must.. ?? or u can use another piece of code ?? if u can use another code, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
        @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        isSignedEnable = true;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                lastTouchX = eventX;
                lastTouchY = eventY;
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                    float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                    float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                    expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                    path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
                }
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;

            default:
                debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
                return false;
        }

        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;


        return true;
    }

    private void debug(String string) {
    }

    private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
        if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
            dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
        } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
            dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
        }

        if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
            dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
        } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
            dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
        }
    }

    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {
        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }
}
```

Then for save image

```
 v.draw(canvas);
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
            mFileOutStream.flush();
            mFileOutStream.close();
            String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
            signimage.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            System.err.println("" + url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You check bitmap is null or not. if null then create bitmap

```
            if (mBitmap == null) {
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        try {
            FileCache fileCache = new FileCache(SignatureActivity.this);
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(fileCache.getFile(imageURL));

            v.draw(canvas);
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
            mFileOutStream.flush();
            mFileOutStream.close();
            String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
            signimage.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            System.err.println("" + url);
            return url;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
        }
        return "";
```